# "Preload key requests" problem in page speed insight, but the tag in code exists

Tags: html, optimization, preload, pagespeed-insights

I have a website https://www.budowle.pl/ which I want to optimize and increase its score in Google Page Speed Insight.

One of the problems I have is:

```
Preload key requests
1.68 pp
Consider using `<link rel = preload>` to prioritize fetching resources that are currently requested later in page load. Learn more.
URL
Potential Savings
/fonts/icons.ttf?myrw8(www.budowle.pl)
```

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.budowle.pl&tab=mobile

I haven't found a way to deal with it :(

In the code I have (according to me :)) the correct tag:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://www.budowle.pl/fonts/icons.woff?myrw8" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
```

I also tried, without this parameter `?myrw8`, but without success.

If anyone has any idea what I could do, I'd appreciate your help.

Kind regards, Wojtek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that you are looking at the wrong file :-P

You have done everything correctly for the "icons.**woff**" but you haven't done `rel="preload"` for the "icons.**ttf**" file.

This appears to be referenced in your `main.css` file.

Now as [`woff` font format has very good support](https://caniuse.com/woff) you may decide to remove the reference to the `ttf` format (which would probably be my recommendation as the browsers that don't support `woff` [don't support `ttf` anyway](https://caniuse.com/?search=ttf) except very old android devices (less than version 4.4)), if not just add a preload for the `ttf` file in the same way.

`<link rel="preload" href="https://www.budowle.pl/fonts/icons.ttf?myrw8" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>`

Comment: Thanks :) How could I not notice it :(
By the way, it's a bit weak to force preloading the font, because we don't known which type the user's browser will use, it could be ttf, woff, woff2, eot or svg.
And when preloading, we force this .ttf to be downloaded, even if the user would use another one. And preloading all types doesn't make sense either probably.

Comment: That is why I recommended using only one of the formats. I mean the real recommendation here would be to **not use a font for icons at all** and instead use SVG. You may want to check out [this answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480154/2702894) (last section mainly). You only use about 20 icons from what I can see so inlined SVGs would probably be better.

Comment: Actually i have 91 icons on whole website,which i extracted from fontawesome and create my own (smaller) font. I know this svg solution and if i had less icons i would consider using svg,but with 91 icons i should u svg+js. Somehow i don't like javascript solution:/

Comment: Well that is fair enough, I would still go for SVG personally just because of accessibility but understandable why you use a font. Good luck with the project and glad the above helped :-)